# How do I make a certain section of a page fit 100% of the screen in all resolutions, yet keep the ability to scroll down?

Tags: html, css

I just recently started coding and so I'm not particularly sure of a lot of things - even what program I'm using. What's the difference between HTML and CSS?

Anyway, back to the question at hand: How do I make a certain section of a page fit 100% of the screen in all resolutions, yet keep the ability to scroll down? This is the website: http://youns.gitastudent.online/

I'm trying to make it so that the 'Computer Science: Gita 1' box is centered on the page for all resolutions, but the scroll function is still there. The button below will scroll the page down to the 'August' heading, should a user click on it.

I also have another button at the very bottom of the website that brings the page back up to the top, but I noticed that it never truly brings it all the way up. I can still scroll up maybe 5-10 pixels - is there a reason for this? How do I fix this?

```
<div class="main" id="Top"></div>
</br></br></br></br></br></br>

<hr width="90px" size="1" color="silver">
<hr width="200px" size="1" color="silver">
<hr width="525px" size="1" color="silver">
<div id="box1" class="Style7">
. . .
</div>
<h1 id="box2"></br>Computer Science: Gita 1</h1>
<div id="box2" style="line-height:20px">
</br>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="Style2">
This is my website for Computer Science 1. We are learning C#</br>which is used for making Windows apps.
This is my first year of programming, but</br>some day I would like be able to program my own apps from scratch.
</div>
<div id="box3" class="Style2">
</br>
</div>
<div id="box4" class="Style7">
. . .
</div>
</br>
<hr width="525px" size="1" color="silver">
<hr width="200px" size="1" color="silver">
<hr width="90px" size="1" color="silver">

</br></br></br></br></br></br>

<div class="Style2">
Projects
</div>
<div class="Style6">
-
</div>
<div><a href="#Projects"><button class="button1">﹀</button></a></div>

</br></br></br></br></br>
<div id="Projects"></div>
<div id="box6" class="Style4" align="center">
</br>
August
</br>
</br>
</div>
</br></br>
```

Comment: I'm really sorry if the way I asked it did not make much sense. Still new to this :(

Comment: See these tutorials [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp) it will be much easier to learn from here in an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

For width to cover the full page you will need to provide `width: 100vw;` which means it will cover the viewport width, 
and also you should consider studying about the use of HTML tags 
for the button for top
you have provided `id #top` in `<center>` tag which is not really at top. You will be able to see when you inspect it. and also, try giving the `id #top` in `body`. it will scroll to all the way up.

Comment: Thanks for the fix suggestion on the `id="Top"`, it's working as I wanted now. I'm not sure that the `width: 100vw` is the code I want because it's not the width I want to fix, but the height. Is there another code for height instead of width?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want with height, if you want it to cover to the whole screen give `height: 100vh;`